# Skipping through a byte array

Tags: arrays, vb.net

In VB .Net 'm building a class object to read a binary database file and process the records.

First I get the total contents of the binary file and then I process it using the .Skip().Take() methods. These methods slow the application unfortunately down too much.

My question is therefor: is there a faster way to process the data than using the .Skip().Take() methods?

Here is some example code:

```
Public Sub ExampleCode(ByVal filename As String)
    Dim length As Long
    Dim content As Byte()
    Dim records As New List(Of Array)

    'Following constants are in actuality extracted from a header...
    Const _NumberOfRecords = 2000000
    Const _NumberOf Fields = 48

    'Get the contant for specified file
    content = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllBytes(filename)

    'Process all fields for this record
    For j As Long = 0 To _NumberOfRecords - 1

        Dim record(_NumberOfFields - 1)
        lastPos = 1320
        For i As Long = 0 To _NumberOfFields - 1
            'Get the field length from_FieldDescriptors that is 
            'normally extracted from a fields section in the binary file
            length = _FieldDescriptors(i).Length

            'Get the value and add it to this record
            record(i) = _Content.Skip(lastPos).Take(length).ToArray

            'Proceed to the next field
            lastPos += length
        Next i
        _Records.Add(record)
    Next j
End Sub
```

Comment: Shouldn't this line `_Records.Add(record)` be `records.Add(record)` ?

Comment: @preciousbetine You're right. The code was in this case copied from an actual application where _Records is the readonly property value for Records...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `_Content` is an `Array`, you may try [Array.Copy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.copy?view=netframework-4.8#System_Array_Copy_System_Array_System_Int32_System_Array_System_Int32_System_Int32_), it should be faster:

```
record(i) = New Byte(length) {}

Array.Copy(_Content, lastPos, record(i), 0, length);
```